# What database should I use that would best suit my GIS application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, gis, postgis

I am currently in the process of developing a program and not sure where to go from here...

I am using Visual C# and the DotSpatial frawework in order to do the GIS/GPS side of things but am unsure of what back end database to use.

I have had a look at PostgrSQL with PostGIS and also had a look at MSSQL as this now has Geospatial capabilities.

So what I am trying to achieve is the following with the software:
- The software needs to be used both at the persons desk, but also remotely while using the GIS/GPS side of the system to track the users travelling. (i.e. when locating where they need to go - this is custom data on remote sites). This is relatively easy to do with DotSpatial alone and not DB is needed.
- They have custom forms that capture data (text, lats/longs, photos) while out on site.
- The data needs to be able to sync up with the main database when they are back in the office
- This data needs to be viewable by everyone connected to the system once the system is updated

Ultimately if this can be a type of DMS then that would be great. So I am keeping that in mind as well.

Should I use a seperate DB for the datacapture side of things and something else for the main DB or should I use the same for both? Which one is easiest to configure? I would prefer when deploying the software that the installation goes smootly and dont have to manually configure each machine.

The main server is Windows 2008 Server btw.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use PostgreSQL with PostGIS on a daily basis. Although it is opensource it provides very good funcionality and performance.

Check this [Cross Compare](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008_postgis_mysql_compare) between SQL Server 2008 Spatial, PostgreSQL/PostGIS 1.3-1.4, MySQL 5-6. This could give you a good idea

Comment: How is the deployment of this? I.e using PostgreSQL and PostGIS? I have rolled out MSSQl a few times, but generally find it difficult for the end user to set it up as part of an installation unless you use windows authentication.

Comment: Yes. You install PostgreSQL as a DBMS. PostGIS adds support to geographic objects. It has a solid community and god step-by-step guides including instalation.

Answer (score 2):

I second the recommendation for PostgreSQL/PostGIS. It works very well and is well supported by the community. I would note that OpenStreetMap uses PostGIS as well. Indeed, if you ever want to work with their data you'll be wanting PostgreSQL.